# How do I declare a public variable in a Module and access the variable in my worksheet objects?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble declaring a public variable and getting my worksheet objects to access it. For example, I have a collection of strings that won't change (does this mean they're static?), defined in a module:

```
Dim List1 As New Collection

Public Sub Definitions()
   With List1
   .Add "Steelers"
   .Add "Vikings"
   .Add "Packers"
   End With
End Sub()
```

Afterward, I would like to call List1 in a private sub from a worksheet:

```
Private Sub CallThis()
Call Definitions
Dim Count as Variant
For Each Count In List1
   ...
Next Count
End Sub
```

However, I get a "Variable not defined" error. What am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List1` is not defined within the scope of `CallThis` subroutine. Use `Option Explicit` to alert you to this sort of problem. This should go in each module and requires all variables to be declared.

```
Option Explicit

Public List1 As Collection
Public Sub Definitions()
   Set List1 = New Collection
   With List1
   .Add "Steelers"
   .Add "Vikings"
   .Add "Packers"
   End With
End Sub
```

In order for your variable to be "public" you need to declare it as such using the `Public` keyword instead of `Dim`.

Note that I set List1 to a new collection each time.  Otherwise, everytime you call Definitions, you will add more items to the collection.

Oh, and you had a syntax error in the final line of your public sub, which I corrected.

Comment: Thanks for the assist!